# how to organize my yarn packages

Tags: node.js, express, yarnpkg

I am new to **Yarn** (read that Bower is deprecated) and I am asking for best practices to distinguish server side libraries from WebUI browser libraries.

I am running a `server.js` (`node.js`) for which I need to install libraries for, I usually leave them in `node_modules`. I used to install them with `npm`

My webapp also has static libraries that I want to have in my `assets` folder.

```
yarn add jquery
yarn install --modules-folder assets/vendor
```

Now it's install all my NPM libraries into `assets/vendor`, but instead I only meant to have `jquery` in there.

How do go around that?

Is Yarn a replacement to NPM?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a good practise to use NPM and Yarn... You have to choose which package manager you want to use!

They are similar, the main goal is to install/uninstall your third party dependencies. They are not replacing each other.

Read Yarn vs Npm: https://blog.risingstack.com/yarn-vs-npm-node-js-package-managers

You can also install `jquery` using `npm install jquery --save` :)

**Structure your packages**

If you are creating a SPA application I would recommend to separate your API and WebApp in a separate repositories.

If you want to use in the same repository, you just need to install your frontend dependencies as a normal dependency (they are all dependencies of your application)! I would recommend you to use webpack to bundle your assets from node_modules to `/app/assets` folder.

Comment: So, you'd use Yarn or NPM for server side and `Webpack` for frontend dependencies. It may be the piece of information that I was missing. I will look at `Webpack`. Cheers

Comment: No, you should use NPM or Yarn for all kind of dependencies! It does not matter if it's backend or frontend! You can use Webpack to get all your frontend dependencies and bundle them in a single file in your folder `/assets` :)

I hope it helped you :)

Comment: Are you saying that should compile all my frontend dependencies in a single file e.g. `production.min.css` and `production.min.js`? I figured I'd only use **WebPack** to copy the files from `node_modules` into my `assets/vendor` folder e.g. `assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/*.min.js` and `assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/*.min.css`. That's how I figured it should go about it, leaving `production.min.js` for my own Javascript code.

Comment: Usually people bundle all external libs into a single .js and css file and another 2 for your js and css files! You can use webpack to do both things copy and bundle your external and own dependencies :)